Assign time record to project in Everhour
In Everhour, I need to assign a time record to an existing Project.
With the Everhour API (https://everhour.docs.apiary.io/) I am able to retrieve:
-information about the time record, as time record id and name
-the project id
I do not see a way to connect a project to a time record, or a time record to a project.
Any suggestion?
I am trying to bridge Pipedrive and Everhour leveraging Everhour capabilities by API

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In the Everhour API there are endpoints to access and operate over Projects and Time Records. I would need help to assign a specific Time Record to a specific Project. In the available documentation there is no clear explanation on how Project information can be assign to a Time Record or how to list and update Time Records in a Project. I hope this issue is clearer now.
